# Grappelli, Filebrowser using a CDN and uploading files locally

Tags: django, django-admin

I believe that this is a settings issue and not something more complicated. When I try to browse the uploads directory Grappelli or Filebrowser set the root URL to the STATIC_URL and I can't see how to change it. I posted the following on the Filebrowser Issues:

> I have the following setup:
>
> Amazon S3 serves all my static files.
>   A local directory on my server handles all my uploads.
>
> When I click the brows icon, the URL root is the STATIC_URL. No matter what settings I tweak in the JS. I can't get it to see the MEDIA_URL.
>
> Any suggestions on how to make this work? It seems like there should be a way to set this, but none of the settings seem to be working.
>
> It doesn't look like I can change where Grappelli is served from. Is that the issue? Any help is welcome.

Any suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that Filebrowser doesn't work with CDNs at this time.